# When do you use an aluminum vs PVC service entrace cap (weatherhead)?

Tags: electrical, code-compliance, conduit

When installing an overhead power service entrance, you can choose between metal conduit with a metal weather-head, or PVC conduit with a PVC weather-head. Is this 100% a matter of preference, or are there specific code requirements that determine which you can or can't use in a given scenario? If there are specific requirements, what are they?

Comment: What’s the mast? If it’s PVC then then the weatherhead must also be PVC.

Comment: The mast and weather-head will be the same material, the question was if there was ever a requirement to use a PVC mast+head vs a metal mast+head, or if it's preference. I understand that they both need to match.